# Chat app android native using C# and Firebase

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc, firebase, chat

I want to develop a chat module in my existing app built using **android native java**. Currently my user account and all data saved in **sql server with backend built on C# MVC framework**. Now I am confused what structure I need to follow to built chat module, I have watched many firebase tutorials but they all used firebase realtime database and save user in firebase database but I already have my data in sql server. Anyone please guide me how start with it or do you guys give any suggestion to me.

Comment: If your data is already stored in SQL Server, and you're already using .NET MVC, what do you want to use Firebase for? Knowing that will drive other decisions, for example: what documentation to read.

Comment: I want to build chat module and will also use firebase push notification for my android client but I am confused how to create chat module which use my exisiting sql server database users but not sure to use these users for realtime chatting.

Comment: How would Firebase be involved in that chat module? For example: if you think of using the Firebase Realtime Database or Firestore for synchronizing the chat messages, what would the relationship between that database and SQL Server be? How would you keep the data in both locations in sync? Do you even need SQL Server for the chat messages at that point, or could you just store the data in Firebase. Those are decisions you will have to make yourself, as there's no right or wrong answer.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please suggest me a better approach. I have users in SQL database and same user login android app through web service. Now What should I need to do make realtime chat and push notifications? Im still confused and not sure what I have to do and how

Comment: How it  would be possible without firebase to make realtime chat app and push notifications using c# backend sql server database

Comment: The problem is that there are hundreds of ways to approach this problem, and none if them is pertinently the best. I recommend following some [tutorials for how to build chat with just Firebase](https://www.google.com/search?q=tutorial+to+build+web+chat+with+Firebase+and+FCM), and then use your experience with MSSQL and ASP.NET to determine your options.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen hello, Is it possible to use my existing user stored in SQL Server and use same user for Firebase Auth and make chat app?